# How to configure the SharePoint Sign in from the Microsoft Project

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ms-project, sharepoint-permissions, sign-in

I've 2 farms (Staging and Production) for the same web application,

When I try to login to the Staging from Microsoft Project, I can see the **default Login component**
[image]

But when I try to login to the Production from the same Microsoft Project, I get this **Windows Security prompt**
[image]

Can anyone please tell me what's the difference and how to get the Default Login component on Production as on Staging ?

Please Note that going to both web apps from the browser will shows the **default Login component** like in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The top picture shows that SharePoint is using FBA or more likely, SAML authentication configured for the Web Application.

The bottom is showing the use of Windows authentication on that Web Application. You would need to configure FBA or SAML authentication against your auth provider on the production web app.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this,
I understand your point but why when I go directly to the mpp file url from the browser
while i'm signed out, it shows me the FBA sign in screen.., why it displays the windows Auth sign in from MS Project ?